# Как в jquery правильно обрабатывать множество похожих событий?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Смотрите: если у меня в коде написано:

```
$(function () {
    $(".review").click(function() {
        $("div").slideToggle(300);
    });
})
```

То при нажатии на любой элемент с классом review, у меня slideToggle сработает на каждый div. Если для каждого div'a и элемента с классом .review задавать отдельный класс, обрабатывая 1 и то же событие, то кода будет слишком уж много:

```
$(function () {
    $(".review1").click(function() {
        $(".div1").slideToggle(300);
    });
})
$(function () {
    $(".review2").click(function() {
        $(".div2").slideToggle(300);
    });
})
$(function () {
    $(".review3").click(function() {
        $(".div3").slideToggle(300);
    });
})
//...
```

Так вот: через цикл перебрать элементы у меня не получается, а писать слишком много кода - не очень... Скажите: как правильно обрабатывать множество одинаковых событий на jquery?

Comment: Обычно такие штуки делают либо через id либо data-атрибуты или же взаимное расположение элементов внутри (i-й review соответствует i-му div-у)

Comment: Покажите вашу вёрстку пожалуйста

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужен $(this).  Хотя из вопроса не ясна проблема. То что все div срабатывают  -это хорошо или плохо?